# Oracle - SubQuery returning Multiple rows

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have the following table structure:

**HSM**

```
HSM_EXC_CODE    Y   VARCHAR2(60)
HSM_INSTR_CODE  Y   VARCHAR2(60)
HSM_ISIN    Y   VARCHAR2(60)
HSM_VWD_TICKERSYMBL Y   VARCHAR2(80)
```

**TENFORE_EXCHANGE_MAP**

```
HS_MARKET   Y   VARCHAR2(40)
TF_EXCHANGE Y   VARCHAR2(40)
```

**TFV**

```
TFE_ID  Y   NUMBER(22)
TFE_VSE_CODE    Y   VARCHAR2(1000)
```

**Different TFE_ID can have same TFE_VSE_CODE!** I think this is what I'm missing in the update query below.

**VSD**

```
VSD_ON  Y   VARCHAR2(160)
VSD_ISIN    Y   VARCHAR2(15)
```

The tables are connected like the following:

```
TENFORE_EXCHANGE_MAP.HS_MARKET   = HSM.HSM_EXC_CODE
TENFORE_EXCHANGE_MAP.TF_EXCHANGE = TFV.TFE_ID
```

I'm trying to fill hsm_isin and hsm_on fields.  To reach the goal I'm  trying to generate  the names from `hsm.hsm_exc_code` . `tfv.tfe_vse_code`. But I'm doing it wrong, cause I'm getting the error from the topic. This is what I have tried:

```
 UPDATE hsm
       SET hsm_isin               =
           (SELECT distinct vsd.vsd_isin
              FROM vsd, tfv, TENFORE_EXCHANGE_MAP
             WHERE vsd.vsd_on = hsm.hsm_instr_code || '.' || tfv.tfe_vse_code
                   AND hsm.hsm_exc_code = TENFORE_EXCHANGE_MAP.HS_MARKET
                   AND TENFORE_EXCHANGE_MAP.TF_EXCHANGE = tfv.tfe_id)
          ,hsm.hsm_vwd_tickersymbl =
           (SELECT distinct vsd.vsd_on
              FROM vsd, tfv, TENFORE_EXCHANGE_MAP
             WHERE vsd.vsd_on = hsm.hsm_instr_code || '.' || tfv.tfe_vse_code
                   AND hsm.hsm_exc_code = TENFORE_EXCHANGE_MAP.HS_MARKET
                   AND TENFORE_EXCHANGE_MAP.TF_EXCHANGE = tfv.tfe_id);
```

Comment: What does the `'Y'` in the table definition mean?  Don't use the implicit-join syntax (comma-separated `FROM` clause) - always explicitly state your joins.  Would it be possible to get some sample data?  And could we also get the exact error code/message?  Also, it should be possible to combine the two subqueries into one (at least it is in general, not sure about Oracle specifically).

Answer (score 0):

There must be more than one line for key in either first or second subquery: 
Try something like:

```
SELECT hsm.hsm_instr_code, 
     count( distinct( vsd.vsd_on ) ) cnt1, 
     count( distinct( vsd.vsd_isin ) ) cnt2
FROM vsd, tfv, TENFORE_EXCHANGE_MAP, hsm
WHERE vsd.vsd_on = hsm.hsm_instr_code || '.' || tfv.tfe_vse_code
AND hsm.hsm_exc_code = TENFORE_EXCHANGE_MAP.HS_MARKET
AND TENFORE_EXCHANGE_MAP.TF_EXCHANGE = tfv.tfe_id
GROUP BY hsm.hsm_instr_code
HAVING count( distinct( vsd.vsd_on ) ) > 1 OR count( distinct( vsd.vsd_isin ) ) > 1
```

**NOTE:** Once you fix multiline problem, you can simplify two subqueries in one, like below:

```
UPDATE hsm SET ( hsm_isin, hsm.hsm_vwd_tickersymbl ) =
           (SELECT distinct vsd.vsd_isin, vsd.vsd_on
              FROM vsd, tfv, TENFORE_EXCHANGE_MAP
             WHERE vsd.vsd_on = hsm.hsm_instr_code || '.' || tfv.tfe_vse_code
                   AND hsm.hsm_exc_code = TENFORE_EXCHANGE_MAP.HS_MARKET
                   AND TENFORE_EXCHANGE_MAP.TF_EXCHANGE = tfv.tfe_id);
```